# Apache spark with apache flume integration

Tags: spark-streaming, flume-twitter

How Spark Streaming can be configured to receive input data from Flume in Java?.  (I am stuck in the code)
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Duration batchInterval = new Duration(2000);
System.out.println("-Starting Spark Context"); 
System.out.println("-Spark_home:" + System.getenv("SPARK_HOME")); 
JavaStreamingContext sc = new JavaStreamingContext(master, 
"FlumeEventCount", batchInterval, 
System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "/home/cloudera/SparkOnALog.jar"); 
System.out.println("-Setting up Flume Stream: " + host + " " + port); 
JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> flumeStream  


=FlumeUtils.createStream(sc,host, port); 
 flumeStream.count().print(); 
 flumeStream.count().map(new Function<Long, String>() 
 { 
 public String call(Long in) { 
return "????????????? Received " + in + " flume events."; 
} 
}).print(); 
System.out.println("-Starting Spark Context"); 
sc.start(); 
System.out.   println("-Finished"); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)
{
Duration batchInterval = new Duration(2000);
System.out.println("-Starting Spark Context"); 
System.out.println("-Spark_home:" + System.getenv("SPARK_HOME")); 
JavaStreamingContext sc = new JavaStreamingContext(master, 
"FlumeEventCount", batchInterval, 
System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "/home/cloudera/SparkOnALog.jar"); 
System.out.println("-Setting up Flume Stream: " + host + " " + port);

Comment: JavaDStream<SparkFlumeEvent> flumeStream = FlumeUtils.createStream(sc, host, port); 
flumeStream.count().print(); 
flumeStream.count().map(new Function<Long, String>() { 
public String call(Long in) { 
return "????????????? Received " + in + " flume events."; 
} 
}).print(); 
System.out.println("-Starting Spark Context"); 
sc.start(); 
System.out.println("-Finished"); 
} 
}

Comment: Please edit your post and paste the code in the post itself. For more details you can see [help] and [ask]

Comment: I have edited my post and placed the  code..could you guide me with the code..